# my tag helper Drop Down Select Will Not render properly in .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core-tag-helpers

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="roles" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="roles" class="custom-select" asp-items="@(new Select List(ViewBag.Roles))">
                    <option value="">Assign Role</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="roles" class="form-control custom-select"  style="height:20px" asp-items="@(new Select List(ViewBag.Roles,"Id","Name"))">
            <option value="">Large select</option>
         </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

```
my drop down in not responsive any help 
how to make drop down responsive
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the value of `ViewBag.Roles` is assigned incorrectly. Here is an example.

In `Index.cshtml`

```
@{

  ViewBag.Roles = new List<MyModel>
  {
    new MyModel{Id=1, Name="thisname"},
    new MyModel{Id=2, Name="thisname2"},
  };
}
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select asp-for="roles" class="form-control custom-select" style="height:20px" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles,"Id","Name"))">
        <option value="">Large select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Result.

[image]

Comment: it not bind with model i don't  have to do manually for retrieving  in action it need to be bind along with model

Comment: Sorry, I did not know your model, so I give this `drop down` as an example.